# How can I delete a poorly named vocabulary?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I've created a couple of vocabularies programmatically, and accidentally included some spaces in the machine names (caused by bad data in an input CSV). I can't delete these vocabularies with `Vocabulary::load($vid)->delete();`, even though I can see the vocabularies names with
`dsm(taxonomy_vocabulary_get_names());`, while `load($vid)` returns `NULL`.

Any ideas on how I can delete these vocabularies? I was able to delete all the terms in a vocabulary, but the reference remains under `admin/structure/taxonomy`.

Comment: I assume you tried to delete them via the UI?

Comment: I did.  It seemed to partially delete the vocabulary and left it in an unstable state

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling that code? Is the `$vid` really right? You say it has spaces in it? Did you try to delete them from the UI?

Under /admin/structure/taxonomies where you have all vocabularies listed, open the operations dropdown and click "Edit vocabulary".

[image]

On the next page click "Delete".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete it from UI if that doesn't work. Install devel_generate module which is included in [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module as a sub module and select option to generate vocabulary and give count as 0. Don't forget to select delete existing vocabulary. It will delete existing vocabulary which will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify - deleting the vocabulary through the UI allowed some of the menu choices, but not others.

I fixed it by doing a database dump and edited the dump with a search and replace (my vocabulary to my_vocabuary) and then importing the edited dump before deleting with the UI.

Not an elegant solution, but it worked.

Comment: did you try with devel_generate , If I remember correctly I was have similar issue and got resolved by it.